# Rearrange the elements of an array of integers(positive) to form a maximum resulting number

Tags: arrays, algorithm

It is an interview question. We have an array of positive integers and we have to rearrange and join the array elements so that the resulting number is maximum number that can be formed using this array.

e.g.:

```
[884 88] -> 88884

[20 19 90] -> 902019

[909 90] -> 90990
```

My Solution: I thought that sort the elements first by most significant digit(MSD) in decreasing order.

i.e for 909 , 12, 88 we will have 909, 88, 12 after sorting and for those having same MSD sort second MSD and keep on doing this.

So for array 909, 99 we will be having 99 and 909 and combine them.
But for array 909, 90 we will have 90, 909, here is a catch since we have 90 common in both numbers so

90

909  ---> here two combination possible, since 90 is common so 9 is left after removing common part from 909, so I will check whether appending this 9 to 90 makes it larger. Here in this case appending 9 in front of 90 we have 990 which greater than 909 so 909 will be followed by 90. So the answer is 90990.

But when I tried to code it I found it difficult to code because of too much complexity involved. Any suggestions?

Comment: Coincidentally, this question was asked in a Python context [very recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532105/constructing-the-largest-number-possible-by-rearranging-a-list) with several working solutions posted.

Comment: I just saw the question. Stackoverflow didn't show it while I searched it but anyways here we can discuss algorithm making it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

let width = min(#digits) in the set of numbers

sort the numbers decreasing by their first width digits only - break ties by sorting numbers with fewer digits first

take the first one

repeat

Comment: it is not gonna work. e.g. 88, 884 width=2 so  after sorting by 88 we have 884 and 88. so take 884 and then 88 forming 88488 which is wrong.

Comment: OK - so I said sort by the first "width" digits only; and you need to prefer the shortest ones first.  Not sure how to express that succinctly

Comment: ok for 90, 909 we have 90909 which is wrong it should be 90990

Answer (score 0):

Here the logic should be. concat both the numbers and and compare it. Take the larger one and sort it acording to revese order. then the reversed array will produce the bigger number. The following is the code in java.

public class ArrangeToFormBiggerNumber
    {
    /**
     * @param args
     */

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer arr[] = {10,9,20};
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Object>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            return -(o1 + "" + o2).compareTo(o2 + "" + o1);
        }

    });
    String res = "";
    for (Integer i : arr)
    {
        res += i;
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a radix sort problem. Need to sort the numbers in decreasing order. and then generate the number.

Answer (score 0):

We have to do a Lexicographic Sort to solve this. Lets say **I1** and **I2** are the integers we have to compare, then take **I1+I2** and **I2+I1** and if ***I1+I2 > I2+I1*** , **I1** should be placed before **I2** else vice versa. Here is the Java implementation of this problem.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class LexicographicSort implements Comparator<Integer> {

public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    String s1 = o1.toString();
    String s2 = o2.toString();
    return (s2+s1).compareTo(s1+s2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LexicographicSort ls = new LexicographicSort();
    Integer[] nums = {9,1,90,907,5};
    Arrays.sort(nums, ls);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```