# Can this cmp function be better written as a key for sorted()?

Tags: python, sorting, cmp

I was writing a solution to the problem of how to generate the maximum integer by rearranging then concatenating integers from a set. I was given that for the maximum integer, the arrangement of any two of its adjacent integers from the set when expressed as an integer is greater than the arrangement of them being swapped. i.e. given {98, 9}; the arrangement 998 is greater than 989. This holds for all the constituent integers in the examples given below.

I needed to write some code that worked for Python 2.7 as well as 3.3 and came up with the following Python code:

```
try:
    cmp     # Python 2 OK or NameError in Python 3
    def maxnum(x):
        return ''.join(sorted((str(n) for n in x),
                              cmp=lambda x,y:cmp(int(y+x), int(x+y))))
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    from functools import cmp_to_key
    def cmp(x, y):
        return -1 if x<y else ( 0 if x==y else 1)
    def maxnum(x):
        return ''.join(sorted((str(n) for n in x),
                              key=cmp_to_key(lambda x,y:cmp(int(y+x), int(x+y)))))

for numbers in [(1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4), (54, 546, 548, 60)]:
    print('Numbers: %r\n  Largest integer: %15s' % (numbers, maxnum(numbers)))
```

This gives output:

```
Numbers: (1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4)
  Largest integer:    998764543431
Numbers: (54, 546, 548, 60)
  Largest integer:      6054854654
```

Now Raymond Hettinger states that 'key=' is superior to 'cmp=' and I tend to agree with him, (before his Pycon 2013 talk ["Transforming code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go)).
My problem is that **I haven't been able to solve the problem with a key function as elegant as the cmp function**.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532105/constructing-the-largest-number-possible-by-rearranging-a-list) has some key-based approaches, but I think this is a rare case where `cmp` is simply better.

Comment: Note that `cmp_to_key` can be used as a decorator.

Comment: I [solved this before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14539943/100297) using a key.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, but the `cmp` answer was *way* simpler, took one try, and was manifestly right on first glance.  Getting the key version right took lots of tries -- at least eight, I think -- and it's tricky enough that it's not clear whether a given key function works or not without thinking very hard.  [PS: congratulations, BTW!]

Comment: I didn't say the solution was easy or obvious. :-P I do also point to `cmp_to_key` in my answer. [And thanks!]

Comment: I may be missing something, but the condition that the string x+y is greater than y+x appears to be the same as saying that the string x is greater than y.  If so, you can do `lst = [str(x) for x in lst]; print ''.join(reversed(sorted(lst)))`.

Comment: @ArminRigo Unfortunately, if `x, y = '9', '98'` then `(x+y > y+x) != (x > y)`.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters for your alternate method for solution. It is very good to know, but the main reason I have asked the question is to ensure that I have not missed a way to succinctly code an answer using the algorithm I mention.

Comment: @Paddy3118: the solution I came up with is the only `key` version I am aware of.

Comment: @Paddy3118: oups, sorry.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite easy way (or i should say principle) to do it: You just have to compare the mantissa of the numbers, e.g:

```
1 -> 1.0
34 -> 3.4
548 -> 5.48
```

and so on…

How can you get that? Well, you have to get the length of the number `length = log10(number)//1` and divide the number by `10**length`:

```
from math import log10
def mantissa(number):
    return number / 10**( log10(number)//1 )
```

Now you can use the mantissa as key function:

```
>>> sorted((1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4), key = mantissa )
[1, 3, 34, 4, 45, 76, 9, 98]
```

So we just have to reverse the `sorted`-result and now we can use it just like you did:

```
>>> for numbers in [(1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4), (54, 546, 548, 60)]:
...     print 'Numbers: %r\n  Largest integer: %15s' % (
                numbers,
                ''.join(str(i) for i in sorted(numbers, key = mantissa, reverse = True))
               )
... 
Numbers: (1, 34, 3, 98, 9, 76, 45, 4)
  Largest integer:    989764543431
Numbers: (54, 546, 548, 60)
  Largest integer:      6054854654
```

Comment: Unfortunately 998... is greater than the 989... of the above solution.