# [Interview]Find the max no that can be formed by any permutation of the arrangement of positive integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array of positive integers, find the max no that can be formed by any permutation of the arrangement. I would like to know if there are any better Data Structures which can allow to give a more elegant solution for problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class FindMaximumNumbersFromPermutation {


    static class DS implements Comparable<DS> {

        int intAtI;
        Integer[] actualInt;

        public DS(int intAtI, Integer[] actualInt) {
            super();
            this.intAtI = intAtI;
            this.actualInt = actualInt;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(DS o) {
            if(intAtI < o.intAtI)
                return 1;
            else if(intAtI == o.intAtI)
                return 0;
            else return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String s="";
            for(int i=0;i<actualInt.length;i++)
                s= s+actualInt[i];
            return s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = {21,9,23};

        List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        int maxLength= 0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            Integer[] digitsArray = getDigitsArray(arr[i]);
            if(digitsArray.length > maxLength)
                maxLength = digitsArray.length;
            list.add(digitsArray);
        }


        List<Integer[]> output = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        for(int currentLength=0;currentLength<=maxLength;currentLength++)
            doWork(list, output, currentLength);

        for(int i=0;i<output.size();i++)
        {
            Integer[] temp = output.get(i);
            for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(temp[j]);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void doWork(List<Integer[]> list, List<Integer[]> output,
            int currentLength) {
        List<DS> dsList = new ArrayList<DS>();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            Integer[] temp = list.get(i);
            if(temp.length>currentLength)
            {
                dsList.add(new DS(temp[currentLength],temp));
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(dsList);
        Map<Integer,List<Integer[]>> map = new TreeMap<Integer,List<Integer[]>>();

        for(int i=0;i<dsList.size();i++)
        {
            DS  ds = dsList.get(i);
            if(!map.containsKey(ds.intAtI))
            {
                List<Integer[]> l = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
                l.add(ds.actualInt);
                map.put(ds.intAtI, l);
            }
            else
            {
                List<Integer[]> l = map.get(ds.intAtI);
                l.add(ds.actualInt);
                map.put(ds.intAtI, l);
            }
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
        for(int i=keys.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            Integer key = keys.get(i);
            List<Integer[]> l = map.get(key);
            if(l.size() ==1)
                output.add(l.get(0));
        }


    }

    static Integer[] getDigitsArray(int integer)
    {
        String s = integer+"";
        Integer[] ret = new Integer[s.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            ret[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i)+"");
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just...sort the array from largest to smallest? This will always be the largest number.

Comment: @SBI Pretty much yes...

Comment: @SBI  This wont work as  {21,9,23} will give 23219 with your approach, rather the correct answer should be 92321

Comment: @abhinav: then sort lexically, not numerically

Comment: There's a counterexample for simple lexicographic sorting algorithm: [32, 321] -> 32, 321 while [32, 324] -> 324, 32

Comment: There are several approaches (in Python, but easily converted) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532105/constructing-the-largest-number-possible-by-rearranging-a-list).

Answer (score 3):

The general case (gluing together arbitrary nonnegative integers, not necessarily digits), IMHO, is quite interesting, for instance

```
 [709, 8, 70, 71, 5, 7] -> 8771709705
 [31, 34, 30, 3]        -> 3433130
 [334, 323, 30, 31, 3]  -> 33433233130
```

The idea is the same as H2CO3 mentioned: array sorting, 
but the implementation (C#) is different

```
private static int Compare(int x, int y) {
  if (x == y)
    return 0;

  // Not that good solution (to compare chars), but easy to implement
  String Stx = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  String Sty = y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  int n = Stx.Length < Sty.Length ? Stx.Length : Sty.Length;

  // Standard lexicographic comparison: 9 > 80, 293 > 2896, 9873 > 986 etc.
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if (Stx[i] > Sty[i])
      return 1;
    else if (Stx[i] < Sty[i])
      return -1;

  // Special case: ab <>= a? 
  // 70 < 7; 78 > 7 etc
  if (Stx.Length > Sty.Length) {
    for (int i = n; i < Stx.Length; ++i)
      if (Stx[i - 1] > Stx[i])
        return -1;
      else if (Stx[i - 1] < Stx[i])
        return 1;
  }
  else {
    for (int i = n; i < Sty.Length; ++i)
      if (Sty[i - 1] > Sty[i])
        return 1;
      else if (Sty[i - 1] < Sty[i])
        return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Then

```
int[] data = new int[] { 709, 8, 70, 71, 5, 7 };
Array.Sort(data, Compare);

StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
  Sb.Append(data[i]);

// 8771709705
String result = Sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "positive integers" are the digits (nothing else makes sense to me given this constraint about the permutation), the solution is simple: sort the array of integers, the first digit of the largest number will be the largest one, the second the second largest, etc. E. g., given an array of digits numbers `1 5 7 3`, the sorted array is `7 5 3 1`, so the largest such number is 7531. Sorting can be done in `O(n log n)`, [or even in `O(n)`](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/abacussort.html).

**Edit:** if numbers are not constrained to be single digits, then extract all the digits from each number, remove duplicates and add them to an array, and do the sorting etc. with that array from now on.

C++ demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>

#define COUNT(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

void add_digits(std::set<int> &digits, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        digits.insert(0);
    } else {
        while (n) {
            digits.insert(n % 10);
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = { 21, 9, 23 };

    std::set<int> digits;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT(nums); i++)
        add_digits(digits, nums[i]);


    std::cout << "The largest number is ";
    for (std::set<int>::reverse_iterator it = digits.rbegin(); it != digits.rend(); it++)
        std::cout << *it;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[And it works, even with numbers with zeroes in them.](http://ideone.com/2nP8nZ)

**Edit 2:** if you don't need the digits to be unique, then use a vector instead of a set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define COUNT(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

void add_digits(std::vector<int> &digits, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        digits.push_back(0);
        return;
    }

    while (n) {
        digits.push_back(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
}

bool intcmp(const int &lhs, const int &rhs)
{
    return lhs > rhs;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = { 21, 9, 23 };

    std::vector<int> digits;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT(nums); i++)
        add_digits(digits, nums[i]);


    std::sort(digits.begin(), digits.end(), intcmp);

    std::cout << "The largest number is ";
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = digits.begin(); it != digits.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the numbers are constrained to be single digits.  The example in the code is 21,9,23 which your algorithm would order to 23,21,9 for a number of 23219, but a better permutation is 9,23,21 because 92321 is greater than 23219.

Comment: Considering you're splitting the multi-digit numbers, which as I understand it, is not desired. anyway: 7,13,3,1, largest number is 73131, and to point it out, thats not simply a sorting from highest to lowest. If you meant that, "the highest first digit of each numbers" would be clearer. Then in descending order. If there are two digits alike, use any multi-digits first.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Yes exactly. I think we need to do sorting on each digit and the print the result. Only thing which I am not sure is the best DS to use for this

Comment: On each digit or each number? That makes quite a bit of a difference.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I've updated my answer accordingly, you can now revoke your downvote.

Comment: I thought the question was any permutation of the numbers in the array (i.e. not on the numbers themselves, rather the order of each number)?

Comment: @ohaal That's not a permutation but a variation. Or is the requirement that each digit must be included exactly the total number of times it appeared in each number explicit?

Comment: From the question: *"Given an array of positive integers, find the max no that can be formed by any permutation of the arrangement."* -- Each element in the array should (as I understand it) be considered a single object, where the task is then to order the objects (i.e. *"the arrangement"*) in a way which gives them the maximum numerical value.

Comment: See Dmitry Bychenko's answer. *"gluing together arbitrary nonnegative integers, **not necessarily digits**"*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32566/discussion-between-h2co3-and-ohaal)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have some 1-digit numbers, some 2-digit, 3-digit, ..., r-digit.

Group you numbers into r lists by number of digits, and sort each of these lists. At each step, the number you append will be the largest element of one of these lists, so this will help if the set of numbers is large relative to r.

E.g., [1,2,21,33,94,9, 88] => [9,2,1] and [94, 88, 33, 21]

```
9  [2,1][94, 88, 33, 21]
994 [2,1][88, 33, 21]
99488 [2,1][33,21]
9948833 [2,1][21]
99488332 [1][21]
9948833221 [1]
99488332211 [] done
```

Next, you need an efficient way of picking the right number from the numbers at the head of your lists.

Start with the shortest number of digits and go through the numbers at the head of the lists in ascending order of number of digits. Store your current candidate (initially the head of the shortest-digit list). If your current candidate K has k digits, and you're comparing to a number S with s>k digits, consider the first k digits of S. If that is bigger than K then make S your candidate. If that is less than K then skip S.

The only tricky case is if they're equal. Then, compare the two orders the pair could go in and choose the one which goes first in the larger of the two to be your candidate. I believe the choice is arbitrary if they're equal, but haven't convinced myself.