# unexpected output, arrays sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, greatest-n-per-group

the output of my code is not as expected

I tried to answer the third question in [Geektime challenge](https://www.geektime.co.il/five-dev-cjallenges/)

- Write a function that sorts a list of positive numbers (only positive, no negative numbers), in such a way that it reaches the largest number. For example, if we take the numbers: [50, 9, 1, 2] the largest number will be 95021.

this is my code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static int Rec(int num1,int num2)
    {
        if(num1<10&&num2<10)
        {
            if(num1==num2)
                return 0;
            if(num1==Math.Max(num1,num2))
                return 1;
            return 2;
        }
        if(num1>10)
            num1/=10;
        if(num2>10)
            num2/=10;
        return Rec(num1,num2);
    }
    public static void SortMe(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.Length-1;i++)
        {
            int check=Rec(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
            int temp1=arr[i];
            int temp2=arr[i+1];
            while(check==0&&(temp1>10||temp2>10))
            {
                if(temp1>10)
                    temp1%=10;
                if(temp2>10)
                    temp2%=10;
                check=Rec(temp1,temp2);
            }
            if(check==2)
            {
                int temp3=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp3;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void MaxNumber(int[] arr)
    {
        SortMe(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
            Console.Write(arr[i]);
    }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
        int[] arr=new int[4];
        arr[0]=50;
        arr[1]=9;
        arr[2]=188; 
        arr[3]=97;
        MaxNumber(arr);
    }
}
```

the output was supposed to be: 99750188, but it was: 95097188.
why? what's the problem in my code??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363171/interviewfind-the-max-no-that-can-be-formed-by-any-permutation-of-the-arrangem/17363821#17363821

Comment: This would be the perfect opportunity to learn how to use the debugger, step through your code and check when the observed behaviour differs from the expected behaviour. In your special case, you will notice, that if you have two numbers `50` and `188` already in the correct order (relative to each other), a number `97` that is bigger than those two, but comes later in the array will never be compared to  `50` anymore, and thus will never find its correct place in the array.

Comment: You got two answers to your question. Do either of them suit you? If so, consider accepting one of them. You could also upvote one or both of them. If not, do you have more information that we could use to may our answers better?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this in string-land rather than integer-land; it feels more like string manipulation than sorting integers.  This is an **O(N x log(N))** solution (the big-O-ness of these leet-code tests is often important).  I make two **O(N)** passes through the input array and then I do a sort.

The idea is to convert each integer into an equi-length string by appending `"9"`s to the end of the value.  So, `"5"` becomes `"599"`.  Then I sort them decending.  Finally, I glue everything together (without the additional trailing 9s).

First I need a structure to hold my intermediate work.  If I were to finish this off, I'd refactor it a bit, removing some of the fields (but they were useful for debugging):

```
public class SortItem
{
    public SortItem(int itemValue)
    {
        RawInt = itemValue;
        RawString = itemValue.ToString();
        Length = RawString.Length;
    }

    public void Extend(int extendToLength)
    {
        Extended = RawString + new string('9', extendToLength - Length);
    }

    public int RawInt { get; set; }
    public string RawString { get; set; }
    public string Extended { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to create a collection of these on the first pass through, *Extend* them on the second pass through, sort them based on the `.Extended` value, and then glue the `.RawString` values together.

To do that:

```
public static string Test (int[] arrayToSort)
{
    var items = new List<SortItem>(arrayToSort.Length);
    var maxLen = 0;
    //first pass, find max length
    foreach (var item in arrayToSort)
    {
        var newItem = new SortItem(item);
        items.Add(newItem);
        if (newItem.Length> maxLen)
        {
            maxLen = newItem.Length;
        }
    }

    //second pass, extend the length of each string
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        item.Extend(maxLen);
    }

    // finally, sort and glue things together
    var sorted = items.OrderByDescending(item => item.Extended);
    var result = sorted.Select(s => s.RawString);
    return string.Join("", result);
}
```

Finally, to test:

```
var result = Test(new[] { 50, 9, 188, 97 });
```

And `result == 99750188`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more succinct implementation of [Flydog57'a idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75723155/11178549) of right-padding the numbers with `"9"`'s:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 50, 9, 188, 97 };
IEnumerable<int> sorted = numbers
    .OrderByDescending(n => Int64.Parse(n.ToString().PadRight(10, '9')));
string result = String.Join("", sorted);
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
```

Output:

```
Result: 99750188
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uTRCz4).

The magic number `10` is the maximum length of a positive `Int32` value (`Int32.MaxValue.ToString().Length`).

The `Int64.Parse` is not really needed. I included it with the intention to make the sorting more efficient, because AFAIK numbers are cheaper to compare than strings.